# Unable to serialize SparkContext in foreachRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to save the streaming data to cassandra from Kafka. I am able to read and parse the data but when I call below lines to save the data i am getting a `Task not Serializable` Exception. My class is extending serializable but not sure why i am seeing this error, didn't get much help ever after googling for 3 hours, can some body give any pointers ?

```
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq((obj.id, obj.data)))
collection.saveToCassandra("testKS", "testTable ", SomeColumns("id", "data"))` 


import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns
import java.util.Formatter.DateTime

object StreamProcessor extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("StreamProcessor")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")

    val topics = args.toSet

    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics)

    stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        try {

          rdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
            iter.foreach {
              case (key, msg) =>

                val obj = msgParseMaster(msg)

                val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq((obj.id, obj.data)))
                collection.saveToCassandra("testKS", "testTable ", SomeColumns("id", "data"))

            }
          }

        }

      }
    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }

  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
  case class wordCount(id: Long, data: String) extends serializable
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  def msgParseMaster(msg: String): wordCount = {
    val m = parse(msg).extract[wordCount]
    return m

  }

}
```

I am getting

> **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable**

below is the full log

> 16/08/06 10:24:52 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1470504292000 ms.0
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
>       at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SparkContext` isn't serializable, you can't use it inside `foreachRDD`, and from the use of your graph you don't need it. Instead, you can simply map over each RDD, parse out the relevant data and save that new RDD to cassandra:

```
stream
  .map { 
    case (_, msg) => 
      val result = msgParseMaster(msg)
      (result.id, result.data)
   }
  .foreachRDD(rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty)
                       rdd.saveToCassandra("testKS",
                                           "testTable",
                                            SomeColumns("id", "data")))
```

Comment: @Suresh The above looks fine to me, but really you should test and see if it meets your goals in terms of performance.

Comment: @ Yuval. Sure Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yuval, is there a way to filter the data? if result.id value is even, i want to save to testTable_Even, if the result.id  value is odd then I want to save to testTable_Odd

Comment: @Suresh I suggest opening a new question as it is a different matter from this one.

Comment: @ Yuval posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811434/spark-streaming-filtering-the-streaming-data

Answer (score 2):

You can not call `sc.parallelize` within a function passed to `foreachPartition` - that function would have to be serialized and sent to each executor, and `SparkContext` is (intentionally) not serializable (it should only reside within the Driver application, not the executor).

Comment: I am working on the Databricks notebook for visual aid.The code runs fine in my Scala IDE, but throws NotSerializableException in the databricks. val predictionAndLabels = testData.map { case LabeledPoint(label, features) =>
  val prediction = model.predict(features)
  (prediction, label)
}


  
//predictionAndLabels.saveAsTextFile("/Sparkspace/result")

Comment: I am working on the Databricks notebook for visual aid.The code runs fine in my Scala IDE, but throws NotSerializableException in the databricks.                                                                                                val predictionAndLabels = testData.map { case LabeledPoint(label, features) =>
  val prediction = model.predict(features)
  (prediction, label)
}
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)  java.io.NotSerializableException:org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics